# pass a function pointer to a template class

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a template class that I have made called `hash`. My template class `hash` takes three non-type parameters. The definition of the `hash` class is below:

```
template <typename array_type, typename ptr_to_hash, typename hash_type>
class hash
{
    public:
    //default constructor
    hash();

    /* Overloaded Constructors */

    // instantiates a hash object and the pointer to the hash_function

    hash(const int&, std::ifstream&, const char*, ptr_to_hash*);


    /* Methods for Hash Class */
    void insert_to_hash();

    // some other stuff    
};
```

As you can see I want my non-type parameter `ptr_to_hash` to be a pointer to my function `void insert_to_hash`. The implementation of the above overloaded contructor looks like:

```
template <typename array_type, typename ptr_to_hash, typename hash_type>
hash<array_type, ptr_to_hash, hash_type>::hash(const int& dim, std::ifstream& in, const char* file, ptr_to_hash* hash_ptr)
{
    // do some stuff to allocate from file

    // point function pointer to correct function
    hash_ptr = &this->insert_to_hash();
}
```

Now in main I am attempting to create a pointer to my hash function. So I first create a `void` function pointer and then pass that to my overloaded constructor:

```
int main()
{
    // create void function pointer
    void (*foo)();

    //create hash obj. from data read in from argv[1]
    hash< member<int>, void(*), member<int> > awesome( count_lines(in,file), in, file, foo);
}
```

In the above `member<int>` is a template struct and `count_lines()` just returns an integer value for the amount lines in the file. When I attempt to do this I get the error

```
no matching function for call to ‘hash<member<int>, void*, member<int> >::hash(int, std::ifstream&, const char*&, void (*&)())
```

When I look at the error above I seem to be passing my `foo` function pointer object as `*&` which of course does not match any function calls in my class.

That is the crux of my problem. I am unsure of how to pass a function pointer that points to my `void insert_to_hash()` in my `hash` class when using templates. I am clearly doing it wrong.

Comment: Why do you say "non-type parameter" when you have "type parameters"?

Comment: @KerrekSB above I have `array_type` which is not tied to a specific type such as `int` or `double`, thus I use non-type. Is this incorrect grammar?

Comment: @Nic `N` a non-type parameter in this example: `template <int N> struct foo { char x[N]; };`. A template parameter declared with `typename` (or `class`) is a type parameter.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think I understand the type parameter, but when you say `template <int N>` isn't `N` type `int`?

Comment: Yes, `int` is a type, but `N` is not a type and it is `N` which is the actual parameter. Thus `N` is a non-type parameter. Conversely, when you say '`typename array_type`', you're saying 'some type or other I haven't chosen yet'. Thus `array_type` is a type parameter. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JMcF absolutely helps! Thanks for the breakdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `foo` as a reference is `void(&)()`, and as a pointer it is `void(*)()`. I would omit the explicit pointer from the template signature and let it be part of the argument:

```
template <typename FPtr> void run(FPtr f) { f(); }

void foo() { /* ... */ }

// ...

run<void(*)()>(foo);
```

You could also declare `run(FRef * f) { f(); }` and say `run<void(&)()>(foo)`, but I wouldn't bother. There's no way to *not* have the pointer in a function pointer, so you might as well absorb it into the argument type itself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using lambda instead of function pointer.

```
hash< member<int>, void(*), member<int> > awesome( count_lines(in,file), in, file, [what ever you want to pass]{});
```

and your problem is definitely that of signature mismatch it clearly states that the signature of function you have used is not what you have declared.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.
First, this line

```
hash_ptr = &this->insert_to_hash();
```

is trying to use the & operator on the RETURN from a CALL to insert_hash() and assign the result to hash_ptr.

Second, if you corrected this, you're still trying to assign a member from an object instance to the function pointer - and you can't.  If you made the insert_to_hash method static you could do this:

```
template <typename ptr_to_hash> class hash
{
public:
    hash( ptr_to_hash hash_ptr )
    {
        hash_ptr = insert_to_hash;
    }

    static void insert_to_hash()
    {
    }
};

int main( int argc, char *argv )
{
    void (*foo)();

    hash< void(*)() > awesome( foo );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, something else occurs - why take the type of function pointer as a template argument when that type is absolutely fixed by the functions defined in the template class?